# How to parse JSON while using variables?

Tags: c#, json

I am parsing JSON using C#

This code works fine:

```
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("API KEY");
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
            Console.WriteLine(DefindexS);
            price = (double)o["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
            currency = (string)o["response"]["prices"]["5021"]["6"]["0"]["current"]["currency"];
            Console.WriteLine("price" + price);
            Console.WriteLine("Currency" + currency);
```

It prints correctly 
price7.11
Currencymetal

here is the catch. The "5021" in both the cases above needs to be replaced by a variable which is set by the user. The JSON data is alright. as long as the number is correct, it will return a proper value.

The variable is DefindexS. I tried parsing by replacing "5021" by DefindexS (I have set the value to 5021) but it gave me an Unhandled Exception error.

Then I tried to format it and  did this:

```
            string realdef = String.Format("\"{0}\"", DefindexS.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(realdef);
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("API KEY");
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
            price = (double)o["response"]["prices"][realdef]["6"]["0"]["current"]["value"];
            currency = (string)o["response"]["prices"][realdef]["6"]["0"]["current"]["currency"];
            Console.WriteLine("price" + price);
            Console.WriteLine("Currency" + currency);
```

The outcome:

"5021"
and then it crashes.. realdef prints as "5021" so the formatting happened properly. Why am I still getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add the quotes around your variable.  So this line of code is not needed:

```
string realdef = String.Format("\"{0}\"", DefindexS.ToString());
```

It should work when you change it to

```
string realdef = DefindexS.ToString();
```

Comment: first you said it didn't work in your reply, so I executed it in LinqPad and saw it working without a problem.  anyway, I see you changed your answer to mention it works now :)

Comment: Yes I ams orry. my bad

Comment: BTW: you might want to remove your API-key from your URL!  I don't believe this key has to be shared, because it's probably linked to your account.  I would even advise you to change it, if possible.

Comment: Did so. Removed the API key